# How to use jenkins pipeline with nvm wrapper plugin?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using pipeline (`Jenkinsfile`) and I need to change node version. i added the Nvm Wrapper Plugin but i don't know how to use it properly from `Jenkinsfile`

should i add the `nvm('...') {}` inside `steps`? or should it be somewhere top level in the `node` step?
currently i don't even have the `node` step - everything is done using `sh`

Comment: did you get any further with this in the end?

Comment: @OACDesigns i added my answer

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar but kept getting a cryptic error: "ERROR: Failed to fork bash".
Maybe I'll give this a shot again tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what worked for me:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("Build") {
      steps {
         nvm(nvmInstallURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh', 
             nvmIoJsOrgMirror: 'https://iojs.org/dist',
             nvmNodeJsOrgMirror: 'https://nodejs.org/dist', 
             version: '8.1.2') {
                    sh "npm install"
                    echo "Build main site distribution"
                    sh "npm run build:dist"
              }
           }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: A few days later I reboot my VM, then it is not working. After debugging for 2 hours, I find that I get to source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh on reboot. That is not a very good way to deploy. So I switch to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Answer (score 5):

this works for me

```
sh 'bash -l -c ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm use <version> || nvm install <version> && nvm use <version> "'
```

example:

```
sh 'bash -l -c ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm use 8.0 || nvm install 8.0 && nvm use 8.0 "'
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest jenkins upgrade (2.319.2 --> 2.387.1) seems to introduce an issue with this nvm-wrapper plugin where it cannot be used more than one time within the pipeline steps. We did not have that problem before the upgrade... but that is how I landed here.

The solution above did not work for me as I needed node+npm binaries to be set on the path after nvm commands were invoked. Here is an adaptation from other solutions that replaces the nvm-wrapper in a scripted pipeline:

```
  env.ECHO_CMD = 'echo $NVM_BIN'
  env.NVM_BIN = sh (
     script: 'bash -l -c "source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh 1>&2; nvm use $NODE_VERSION 1>&2 || nvm install $NODE_VERSION 1>&2 && nvm use $NODE_VERSION 1>&2 && $ECHO_CMD "',
     returnStdout: true
  ).trim()
  echo "NVM_BIN: ${env.NVM_BIN}"
  env.PATH = "${env.NVM_BIN}:${env.PATH}"

  // do some node stuff in sh commands...
  sh 'node --version'
  sh 'npm --version'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this and it works also  with a .nvmrc file

```
sh 'bash -l -c ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm use || nvm install && nvm use"'
```

This expects nvm installed in the jenkins home folder. But it would be easy to add a step that downloads nvm in the right place first.